# Initializing a string with the empty string

Tags: c, string, strcmp

I was wondering if it is possible to initialize a string with an empty string like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* some_function() {
    char* w = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    w = "";
    if (1 == 2) {
        w = "Not empty anymore";
    }
    return w;
}

int main(void) {

    char* word = some_function();
    int r = strcmp("", word);

    printf("%s\n", word);
    printf("%d\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles fine and gives me the result I want, however I'm still quite new at C and was wondering if this would lead to any problems down the line. Also is my use of strcmp to compare word to "" ok?

Comment: In the code, what `if (1 == 2)` represents ?

Comment: I just put that in so the if statement is false and doesn't execute, so the string returned is the empty string. Basically I'm wondering if it's ok to initialize an empty string like that and return it in the function. In reality, the if statement may or may not be true, ending up with the function returning the empty string or the string "Not empty anymore"

Comment: It is not advisable to do so, rather doing initializing like above, you can use `strcpy()` function.

Comment: 1) Instead of assigning using `=`, use `strcpy`. 2) Include `stdlib.h` (for `malloc` and `free`) 3) `free` the allocated memory from `main`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it's sort of possible, but it won't behave the way you expect.  And in more recent versions of C, it's *undefined behaviour*.

What you did was allocate memory and then throw that pointer away, thus leaking that memory.  You replaced the pointer with a *non-constant* pointer to a *string literal* (which should make your compiler emit a warning or an error).

This happened to work in your case.  Fortunately you didn't try to write to that memory.  If you did, chances are that bad stuff will happen.

Comment: "_which should make your compiler emit a warning or an error_" -- In C, `const` isn't required. There won't be any warning. (I know that `const` *is* strongly recommended when pointing to a string literal).

Answer (score 3):

Uh, oh! You allocate memory for a string and store the handle to the allocated memory in `w`:

```
char* w = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
```

In the next line, you overwrite that handle with an immutable string literal:

```
w = "";
```

That means that (1)  you can no longer free `w` as you should after using it and (2) that `w` now points to a string in read-only memory whose modification will lead to undefined behaviour, most likely a crash.

The dynamically allocated memory behaves like an array. C strings are character arrays that contain the valid characters of the string up to a null terminator, `'\0'`. There fore, setting the first character to the null character will give you an empty string:

```
*w = '\0';
```

or

```
w[0] = '\0';
```

In the dead branch, you want to fill the character array with the contents of a string, but you assign a read-only literal, too. You can use the function `strcpy` from `<string.h>` to fill a character array with a string:

```
strcpy(w, "Not empty anymore");
```

You must make sure, however, that the array is big enough to hold the string plus the terminating null character.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is my use of strcmp("", word) ok though?

Comment: Yes. For `strcmp` it doesn't matter whether the string is read-only or not, because `strcmp` only inspects the string. When you construct your own strings character by character, make sure that the string has the null terminator `'\0'` at the end. And when you allocate memory for a string, make sure that there is room for the additional null character. In your case, the string can contain 99 characters plus the null character.